# "ERR_PNPM_NO_SCRIPT Missing script: tsc" when I run the command "pnpm run tsc"

Tags: typescript, build, package-managers, tsc, pnpm

I'm trying to run `pnpm run tsc` and I get the following error

```
ERR_PNPM_NO_SCRIPT  Missing script: tsc
```

How can I solve the issue? Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you install `typescript` first?

Comment: Thank you! Yes I have typescript installed on the machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pnpm` is complaining that `package.json` doesn't have a script named `tsc` in the `scripts` section.

Try executing it like `./node_modules/.bin/tsc` instead or create an entry in the scripts section of `package.json` like the following snippet:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Adding tsc in the package.json solved the issue, to be honest I thought it was there already but I should have checked